Component in Angular 17 doesn't read signal change
I am setting from component A the value of a signal through a service. When I want to access the signal from component B (not the child) it returns null (the initial value of the signal). In Angular 16 I am almost sure that it worked, Angular 17 change something?
Service
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OneService {
    private _selected = signal<Selected | null>(null);
    public selected = computed(() => this._selectedLead());

    setSelectedLead(selectedItem: Selected) {
        this._selectedLead.set(lead);
    }
}

Component A
@Component({
    selector: 'app-selection',
    standalone: true,
    providers: [OneService],
    imports: [...],
    templateUrl: './selection.component.html',
})
export class LeadsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
        private oneService: OneService,
    ) {}

onRowClick(selectedItem: Selected) {
        this.oneService.setSelectedLead(item);
        this.generalLeadDialog = true;
console.log("SIGNAL FROM COMPONENT A: ", this.oneService.selected())
    }




Problem is that you have multiple instances of OneService.
In OneService you have @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}), that will create global instance of OneService.
Then in Component A you have providers: [OneService], that will create instance of OneService inside of Component A scope, in which you set signal value.
Component B probably use global instance of OneService, and your value is set in Component A scope.
Solution would be to remove providers array from Component A and from Component B (if it is present there) so then both components use same instance of service.
Read here more about providing service, hope this helps! https://angular.io/guide/providers

Thanks for the information! It's still not working, but doing what you suggest, one of the tests I had done makes it work! What I did was create another service, "SecondService," and in it, I created a method that accesses the signal (through OneService). Then I injected SecondService into component B, and there it reads the signal. If I inject OneService into component B, it doesn't read the value of the signal. I'm not sure what could be happening.

Would be helpful if you could create stackblitz with reproduction steps. One problem could be that signal reads execute before it write, also try with adding effect(() => {console.log(this.oneService.selected())}), to constructor, this should run when selected signal changes, and read what value is there.

since you have providedIn: "root" in your service then why do you define this service in providers of any component at all? there is no need to set providers on components with this service, just let it be in "root" and it should work

@lukap123456 it worked but my question is do we have to always use same instance of service when using Signals.
instead of => {providedIn: root}
can we use => providers:[TodoService]
because the thing which i am not able to understand is that if we have to use root injector then what is the point of using SIGNALS because since we are using same instance of service

@SumitKhanduri this has nothing to do with signals. For signals and when to use them there are plenty of articles on the web. Same would happen if selected variable is of any other type. It is just wrong approach to use 2 different instances of a service and expected behavior is that they share same variables/values.

Your service code snippet seems to be correct.
So, I couldn't reproduce your issue and service with signal works well.
**Make sure your variable are correct **
1: create service with signal mechanism
@Injectable(
  { providedIn: 'root'}
)
export class OneService {
  private _selected = signal<Selected | null>(null);

  public selected = computed(() => this._selected());

  setSelectedLead(selectedItem: Selected) {
      this._selected.set(selectedItem);
  }
}

2: create 2 components (A & B) that uses this service.
// component A
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './component-b.html',
})

  constructor(
    public oneService: OneService,
  ) {}

// Component B
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b',
  standalone: true,
  // providers: [OneService], <------- without OnService here
  templateUrl: './component-b.html',
})

  constructor(
    public oneService: OneService,
  ) {}

...
  onRowClick(selectedItem: Selected) {
    this.oneService.setSelectedLead(selectedItem);
    console.log("SIGNAL FROM COMPONENT A: ", this.oneService.selected())
  }

...
The service with root specifies that Angular should provide the service in the root injector.
So in your case (share state between components through a service) you don't need to inject this service (onService) in each providers of components.
The value of signal is updated each time an item is clicked.
Please check the full code:
Stackblitz Demo

providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient(withFetch())]
add this in you app.config.ts file and remove service in the local component provider
